# Different 'run' and 'submit' results (Leetcode #257 Binary Tree Paths)

Tags: python

I've written out a basic solution for [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-paths/submissions/) leetcode problem.

For the failing test case ( [] ), 'Run Code' yields the correct result ( [] ); however, 'Submit' yields an incorrect result ( ["1->2->5","1->3"] ).

The 'Submit' yields an output identical to the original testcase... however, I'm not sure why this would occur because the input is evidently different.

Any tips appreciated.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution(object):
    global paths
    paths = [ ]

    def binaryTreePaths(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        
        if (root):
            curr_path = str(root.val)
            self.binaryTreePathsHelper(root.left, curr_path)
            self.binaryTreePathsHelper(root.right, curr_path)
        
        return paths
    
    def binaryTreePathsHelper(self, node, path):
        
        # so the leaf (base case) has no children
        # base case
        if (node):
            path = path + "->" + str(node.val)
            
            if (not node.left and not node.right):
                paths.append(path)
            else:
                # append curr_node
                # & recursively call
                self.binaryTreePathsHelper(node.left, path)
                self.binaryTreePathsHelper(node.right, path)
```

Answer (score 0):

`paths` is defined at the Solution class level as global.  Consequently, it is initialized to an empty list and not reinitialized if a Solution object is reused or even if more than one Solution object is created.  So once a non-empty result is generated, it will hang around in `paths`, polluting later results.  It would be better to make `paths` an instance attribute and initialize it in the `binaryTreePaths` method.